# What role does App Group play in Apple OAuth?

Tags: oauth, ios-app-group

I own multiple apps and am wondering what the significance would be if they were bundled under the same App Group. I want to synchronize user information across various apps under the same developer account. Specifically, I'd like the 'sub' token in the id_token, returned when logging in via OAuth with the same Apple account in each app, to be identical.

Can this requirement be fulfilled using App Group?